# SELECT * FROM db.table TABLESAMPLE(10 PERCENT)

Tags: mysql

i know this question has been asked but none solved my problem, i am working on localhost with phpmyadmin server version:10.1.21-MariaDB, i want to select n random rows from a large table using the query.....

```
SELECT * FROM db.table TABLESAMPLE(10 PERCENT)
```

but i receive an error statement as........
"#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '(10 PERCENT) LIMIT 0, 25' at line 1"
please this has hooked me for 3days now, your assistance is appreciated

Comment: You have to love MySQL’s error messages. “You have an error … check the manual”. Very helpful.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think MariaDB/MySQL supports `tablesample`.

You can get a 10% sample using `rand()`:

```
select t.*
from db.table t
where rand() < 0.1;
```

This is not *exactly* the same, because the number of rows may not be exactly 10%.  However, for most purposes, it should be close enough.

Answer (score 0):

Use below query:

Select * FROM db.table_name ORDER BY rand();

Comment: @Gordon and Hamja, i thought rand() has slow performance, please do you know how i can increase the speed of request